# Removing all messages in SVN ADD for msbuild script

Tags: svn, msbuild, tortoisesvn

I want to automatically add a set of files using msbuild

```
<Exec Command="svn add %(SVNFiles.Fullpath)  --quiet"  IgnoreExitCode="true" />
```

The problem with this msbuild-task is that it is not quiet enough. The `-q` option removes some but not all messages.

The output windows still shows this message per file that was already added:

```
1>  svn: E200009: Could not add all targets because some targets are already versioned
1>  svn: E200009: Illegal target for the requested operation
```

how can i get svn completely quiet?

(VS2010 express and Tortoise SVN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `&gt; NUL 2&gt;&amp;1` to the end of your command; not MSBuild related but basic Windows batch redirect.